# extending a htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

I have following rewrite rule/condition in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?user_id=$1 [L]
```

The result is "example.com/id1"

Now the problem I have, I need to put a $_GET parameter **sometimes** to the URL, but actually they get ignored, example:

```
example.com/id1?section=video
example.com/id1?section=photo
example.com/id1?section=audio
```

Also not working:

```
example.com/id1&section=video
```

Is there a chance to accomplish this task by extending the htaccess rule? Remember that the URL not always have the $_GET parameter added.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag

```
RewriteRule ^id([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?user_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```